# Find the values of the parameters for which the matrices commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, parametric

> I have two matrices:
>   $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & a \\
> b & 6
> \end{array} \right)
> %
> \ \ \ \ B = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
> 4 & c \\
> d & 2
> \end{array} \right)$.
>   How can I find the values of the parameters $a, b, c, d$ for which the matrices will commute?

I tried calculate $AB$ and $BA$ and compare the matrices elements, but that is not enough to get the result.

I think this have simple solution, but I have difficulties with it.

Comment: So you have found four equations. Did you try and solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
1&a\\
b&6\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
4&c\\
d&2\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
4+ad&c+2a\\
4b+6d&bc+12
\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$BA=\begin{pmatrix}
4&c\\
d&2\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&a\\
b&6\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
4+bc&4a+6c\\
d+2b&ad+12
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence

\begin{eqnarray}
ad&=&bc\\
0&=&2a+5c\\
2b+5d&=&0\\
\end{eqnarray}

Thus $a=\frac{-5}{2}c$ and $b=\frac{-5}{2}d$ and thus $\frac{-5}{2}cd=\frac{-5}{2}dc$ is automatic. In other words for all $c,d$ and $a=\frac{-5}{2}c$ and $b=\frac{-5}{2}d$ the matrices commute.

Although the equations you get are not linear, a solution to the linear second and third equation automatically gives a solution to the non-linear equation! That makes this easy.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$AB - BA = 0$$

$$$$$$$$